# react navigation header button function call within tabnavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have the following navigation config file. This config file use react navigation to create navigators. My question is how can i call a function from 
my navigation config file that is define is another component such as a separate 
screen competent. In the below code i want to be able to call the  showAlert()
from the header button of the Map route. Please note that the showAlert()
is define in the Map screen component below my navigator config.

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator ({
        Map:{screen:MapScreen},
        Profile:{screen:ProfileScreen},
        Consent: { screen: ConsentScreen },
     },
        {



        tabBarOptions: {
             activeTintColor: 'tomato',
             inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
           }
      }


);


Tabs.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { routes, index } = navigation.state;
  const navigationOptions = {};
if (routes[index].routeName === 'Map') {
   navigationOptions.headerRight= (
                               <Button
                                 onPress={routes.showAlert()}
                                 title="Search"
                                 color="#009688"
                                 backgroundColor="white"
                                 icon={{name:'search',color:'#009688'}}
                               />
                             );

}



 if (routes[index].routeName === 'Profile') {
    navigationOptions.headerRight= (
                            <Button
                              onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('settingaccount')}
                              title="Settings"
                              color="#009688"
                              backgroundColor="white"
                              icon={{name:'settings',color:'#009688'}}
                            />
                          );
     navigationOptions.headerLeft= (
                                 <Button
                                   onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('profileEdit')}
                                   title="Edit Profile"
                                    icon={{name:'account-circle',color:'#009688'}}
                                    color="#009688"
                                    backgroundColor="white"
                                    color="#009688"
                                 />
                               );


 }

 if(routes[index].routeName === 'Consent'||routes[index].routeName === 'Map'){
 navigationOptions.headerLeft= null

 }

  return navigationOptions;
}
```

//Screen component

```
class Map extends React.Component {

  showAlert() {
    Alert.alert('No Internet',
      'Check internet connection',
      [
        { text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed') },
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    )
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <View />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey your problem is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567738/accessing-method-of-another-component-on-react-native

What you need to do is access the child methods using "ref".
Or you can call the method from the parent using the props of the child component.

Comment: Hi this is not the same issue, that issue was between two class however my tab bar navigator is not a class it’s just a configuration of react navigation routes that are exported and use within other places of the app.